# Restrict file access only allow read from google cast

Tags: javascript, php, html, chromecast, google-cast

I am using these 2 api to watch the videos of my website on tv, it works fine

```
<script src = "https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js?loadCastFramework=1"> </script>
<script src = "https://fenny.github.io/ChromecastJS/chromecastjs.js"> </script>

cc.cast ({
         content: 'examplewebsite.com/ videos/video1' + '.mp4'
     })
```

I have the videos in, (example) examplewebsite.com/videos/, but the problem is that people can download the videos and see them in the browser if they do examplewebsite.com/videos/video1.mp4, I want to know a way to disable downloading and watching the videos, i wanmt only that the cast works.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to do effective DRM. This is impossible, and will only result in frustrating your legitimate users.

Comment: Why impossible ? , the users never see the video in the website , i only cast it to tv

Comment: @LucasLecce The Web browser needs to tell the Chromecast where the video is somehow, and whatever method you come up with, the user can see it too.